# Make animation so that there is no transformation in between keyframes?

Tags: animation

I created an with these cubes. Every 10th key frame, the cube is duplicated and moved over. However, in the time in between each key frame it shows the cube sliding into the next slot. I don't want this, I just want the cube to appear in the next slot. Is there any way I can make it so there's no sliding animation? Thanks!

What I'd like it to look like (except slower):

[image]

What it looks like right now:

[image]

As you can see, the cubes in the second image (my animation,) are sliding instead of appearing in place like in the first animation. How do I get rid of this sliding? Thanks!

Comment: Two approaches come to mind - either keyframe them at frame 9 -and- 10, so the movement is effectively instant, or (better as I think it avoids motion blur if you turn that on later) change the interpolation of the animated properties so it doesn't interpolate at all, just jumps between values.  I would also put them all in the right places and animate the visibility of them rather than the location, if that works for your specific requirements.

Comment: Is it several separated cubes or one object with several cubes inside of it?

Comment: @Ben Do you think you could show me how to do that please? I'm new to animation lol.

Comment: @lemon They're seperate.

Comment: You could also build the end result and then animate the "Disable in Renders" property in the Outliner (after activation of that Outliner Filter). Or "Show in Renders" in the Visibility section of the Object Properties. (they are same property but in different UI locations by the way.) You would be making them appear and disappear instead of moving. You can hover over the camera icon in the Outliner (or the dot next to the checkbox in the Object Properties) and press I to insert a keyframe.

Comment: Change the interpolation to contstant, so that there is no change in between keyframes

Comment: @susu Ty! I just found that out, works great! :D

Comment: @MmmChezBurgerz please write an answer detailing your solution. Others with a similar issue can learn from you.

Answer (score 2):

That can be a **driver**

[image]

If many cubes, certainly you don't want to animate them all, so use a driver:

[image]

Using the selected cube in the image above, add a driver to its "show in viewports" (**and when all is good do the same for "show in renders"**).

The driver uses some other object's location (an empty) and uses the formula on its x location (named `e` for empty):

> e <= (self.location.x + self.location.y * 5 + self.location.z * 20)

The empty is animated along X axis from 0 to the amount of cube (multiplied by the size of the cubes).

When the empty moves, we want to change the cube visibility from false to true (so hide_viewport from true to false).

If you want to go along X, then Y, then Z, the formula takes the empty X position and test it over the cube location.

> e <= (self.location.x + self.location.y * 5 + self.location.z * 20)

is to:

- change over X
- every y * 5 locations because 5 cubes along x when x changes
- and every z * 20 locations because 5 * 4 cubes along z when z changes

Pragmatically:

Set this driver for the first cube, the one at (0, 0, 0),

then select all the cubes and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> and *"animation data"*.

[image]

this will copy the driver to all other cubes and make the animation.

[image]